# "No such file or directory" Why does my c build file can't build my exe if my files are in the right place?

Tags: c

Why is my build code won't working informing that my file is not acessible if it is in the right folder and my c debugger work as well, finding no errors?

This is my build file:

> set files=src\glad.c src\main.c set
> libs=C:\Users\Ozzy\Documents\projects\c\lib\SDL2main.lib
> C:\Users\Ozzy\Documents\projects\c\lib\SDL2.lib
> C:\Users\Ozzy\Documents\projects\c\lib\freetype.lib
>
> CL /Zi /I C:\Users\Ozzy\Documents\projects\c\include %files% /link
> %libs% /OUT:mygame.exe

```
    OpenGL loader generated by glad 0.1.35 on Fri Jun 10 23:39:07 2022.

    Language/Generator: C/C++
    Specification: gl
    APIs: gl=3.3
    Profile: core
    Extensions:
        
    Loader: True
    Local files: False
    Omit khrplatform: False
    Reproducible: False

    Commandline:
        --profile="core" --api="gl=3.3" --generator="c" --spec="gl" --extensions=""
    Online:
        https://glad.dav1d.de/#profile=core&language=c&specification=gl&loader=on&api=gl%3D3.3
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <glad.h>
```

[Print of the error and folder tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwhMI.png)

Comment: Please do not post an external link with images of your code, just write your code in your question. You may want to read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshot I can see that the `glad` directory is next to `main.c`.

When including files, you can use either quotes (`""`) or angle brackets (`<>`), and they behave differently. The exact behavior depends on the compiler you are using and the settings for that compiler, but with `cl.exe` the default behavior is:

- `<>`: Search within your include paths (which can be set using the [`/I`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories?view=msvc-170) flag).
- `""` Search relative to the location of the including file. If that doesn't work, fall back to the include paths.

So if you replace:

`#include <glad/glad.h>`

With:

`#include "glad/glad.h"`

Then it should work.

[Here's some more information about how the `#include` directive works in `cl.exe`/MSVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-include-directive-c-cpp?view=msvc-170).